# how to set default value for element if that element is absent in xml file through jaxb unmarshalling in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

The issue is I want to set a default value for "name" element which is absent in input.xml file.How can I achieve this through jaxb?, I dont want to do it through java model. Is there a way to get it through shema or through jaxb.
Below is the code:

**1. customer.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="stringMaxSize5" minOccurs="0" default="ss"/>
                <xs:element name="phone-number" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" default="200" />
             </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="stringMaxSize5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**2. Customer.model**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "phoneNumber"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "ss")
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "phone-number", defaultValue = "200")
    protected BigInteger phoneNumber;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
    public BigInteger getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(BigInteger value) {
        this.phoneNumber = value;
    }
}
```

**3. input.xml**

```
<customer>

</customer>
```

For unmarshalling using the below code:

```
SchemaFactory sf =SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("customer.xsd"));

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));
System.out.println(customer.getName() + "   " + customer.getPhoneNumber());
```

By running this I am getting null value for the name and If I use the below input.xml file with "name" element  then I am getting default value for name field.

```
input.xml file:
<customer><name/></customer>
```

So,how to set default value for missing element through jaxb?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your XML document are missing the elements. See the [JAXB guide](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Element_default_values_and_unmarshalling.html)

> When a class has an element property with the default value, and if the document you are reading is **missing the element**, then **the unmarshaller does not fill the field with the default value.** Instead, the unmarshaller **fills in the field when the element is present but the content is missing**

Try this input document

```
<customer>
    <name/>
    <phone-number/>
</customer>
```

Comment: yes that way I am getting the default value for the element but there is a use case in which I don't want to specify the blank element and even then I want to set default value.So is there a way to do that?

Comment: According to the documentation is not possible with JAXB. In this case, you can set the default value in Java code `String name= "default";`